# Binary code Error help

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search

I forgot to insert my code, sorry on my behalf..

I have a Binary Search going in my program, but when I enter 10 student records into an Array and sort them, the last element of Student ID will not be picked up from my binary search.

Say when I sort the Array and 232 was the last element in the Array, when I go to Search 232 the Binary Search Function gives me back not found and I look for any other ID with in the array and give it back with the records.

```
  else if ( choice == 4) // Binary Search... This Also Force Array to be Sorted If Array is not Sorted. 


        {


            merge_sort(0,N_STUDENT-1);

            cout<<" \n\t Enter the student number to search :"; // Ask user to Input Student ID. 
            cin>>key;

            k=binarySearch(record, 0, N_STUDENT-1, key); // Serach Array 

            if(k>=0) 

                cout<<"Student Details with student Number\n "  <<key<<  "exists at the position \n"  << k
                << " Student Number\n" << record->student_number << "  "  << " Student Name \n" <<  record->studentname << "  " << " Student Address \n" << record->Address << "   " << " Course Code \n"  <<  record->CourseCode << "   "   <<  " Course Name \n" << record->CourseName; //Displays Position of Student And Student Details.
            else 
                cout<< "Not found "; // if Record is not Found 


_____________________________________________________________________________________________________

//function binary search using the key value to serach 


int binarySearch(student  sorted[], int first, int upto, int key) {  // Sort Array if not Sorted... 

    while (first < upto) {
        int mid = (first + upto) / 2;  // Compute mid point.
        if (key<sorted[mid].student_number)
        {
            upto = mid;     // repeat search in bottom half.
        } else if (key>sorted[mid].student_number) 
        {
            first = mid + 1;  // Repeat search in top half.
        } else 
        {
            return mid;     // Found it. return position
        }
    }
    return -(first + 1);    // Failed to find key
}
```

Comment: I tried to clean it up for you a bit, but damn that's some really ugly code -.-

Comment: Where is the definition of your array? If it has `N_STUDENT` elements then search and sort to `N_STUDENT` not `N_STUDENT-1` to include the last element.

Comment: Depends what `merge_sort` does, but yes that is indeed the case with his binary search function.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, your `upto` is actually an exclusive bound, so replace your 6th line with:

```
k=binarySearch(record, 0, N_STUDENT, key); // Serach Array
```

Generally speaking, copying code without understanding it is a poor way to do homework. The time will come when your horrible looking pastes will be overlooked by StackOverflow users and you'll be unable to finish it.

Comment: I Saw the code on a Site that i was giving in College. that give you sample codes, so i saw that and i edit to suit my needs. -1 is forcing Sorting if sorting is not Done, so to allow Binary Search to work.